# Is there any demo to show how to use the placeholder like this in Scala?

Tags: scala

I found "strange" usage of placeholder in Scala:
In [precompiler-in-scala](https://github.com/scalate/scalate/blob/c3fa76f0f06559903be5001e2cac2429bd8eacc7/scalate-core/src/main/scala/org/fusesource/scalate/support/Precompiler.scala)

```
class Precompiler {
  var sources = Array[File]()
  var workingDirectory: File = _
  var targetDirectory:File = _
  var templates = Array[String]()
  var info:{def apply(v1:String):Unit} = (value:String)=>println(value)
  var contextClass:String = _
  var bootClassName:String = _
  // ...
}
```

Is this the partial function? Or anything else? And is there any demo to show usage of the placeholder like this?

Comment: There's a dozen different meanings to `_`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, no, it's just boring-old `null`. From the [Scala Language Spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> A variable definition var x : T = _ can appear only as a member of a
>   template. It introduces a mutable field with type T and a default initial
>   value. The default value depends on the type T as follows:
>
> ```
>   0        if T is Int or one of its subrange types,
>   0L       if T is Long,
>   0.0f     if T is Float,
>   0.0d     if T is Double,
>   false    if T is Boolean,
>   ()       if T is Unit,
>   null     for all other types T .
> ```

It might be clearer just to write `null` in these cases. I guess `_` might look more Scala-y.